# Adding multiple static text overlays to inline SVG

Tags: html, css, svg, overlay

What is the best practice in adding multiple text overlays to an inline SVG?  In my example, I'm showing a region of states.  I simply need to add the two letter state code over each state.  I'd also like to retain the info-box popup (even though it appears redundant in the example).

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7jLu1rdb/)

```
<svg 
    xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" 
    xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape" 
    xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd" 
    xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
    version="1.1" id="us-map" 
    preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" 
    sodipodi:docname="southeast.svg" 
    inkscape:version="0.91 r13725" 
    x="0px" 
    y="0px" 
    width="600px" 
    height="550px" 
    viewBox="690 398 330 282" 
    xml:space="preserve"
>
<a href='#' title="South Carolina">
    <path id="SC" data-info="<div>South Carolina</div>" fill="#815C6E" d="M935.2,512.9l-1.8,1l-2.6-1.3l-0.6-2.1l-1.3-3.6l-2.3-2.1l-2.6-0.6l-1.6-4.8l-2.7-6l-4.2-1.9   l-2.1-1.9l-1.3-2.6L910,485l-2.3-1.3l-2.3-2.9l-3.1-2.3l-4.5-1.8l-0.5-1.5l-2.4-2.9l-0.5-1.5l-3.4-5.2l-3.4,0.2l-4-2.4l-1.3-1.3   l-0.3-1.8l0.8-1.9l2.3-1l-0.3-2.1l6.1-2.6l9.1-4.5l7.3-0.8l16.5-0.5l2.3,1.9l1.6,3.2l4.4-0.5l12.6-1.5l2.9,0.8l12.6,7.6l10.1,8.1   l-5.4,5.5l-2.6,6.1l-0.5,6.3l-1.6,0.8l-1.1,2.7l-2.4,0.6l-2.1,3.6l-2.7,2.7l-2.3,3.4l-1.6,0.8l-3.6,3.4l-2.9,0.2l1,3.2l-5,5.5   L935.2,512.9z"/>
</a>
<a href='#' title="Georgia">
    <path id="GA" data-info="<div>Georgia</div>" fill="#815C6E" d="M863.6,458l-4.8,0.8l-8.4,1.1l-8.6,0.9v2.2l0.2,2.1l0.6,3.4l3.4,7.9l2.4,9.9l1.5,6.1l1.6,4.8l1.5,7   l2.1,6.3l2.6,3.4l0.5,3.4l1.9,0.8l0.2,2.1l-1.8,4.8l-0.5,3.2l-0.2,1.9l1.6,4.4l0.3,5.3l-0.8,2.4l0.6,0.8l1.5,0.8l0.6,3.4l2.6,3.9   l1.5,1.5l7.9,0.2l10.8-0.6l21.5-1.3l5.4-0.7l4.6,0l0.2,2.9l2.6,0.8l0.3-4.4l-1.6-4.5l1.1-1.6l5.8,0.8l5,0.3l-0.8-6.3l2.3-10   l1.5-4.2l-0.5-2.6l3.3-6.2l-0.5-1.4l-1.9,0.7l-2.6-1.3l-0.6-2.1l-1.3-3.6l-2.3-2.1l-2.6-0.6l-1.6-4.8l-2.9-6.3l-4.2-1.9l-2.1-1.9   l-1.3-2.6l-2.1-1.9l-2.3-1.3l-2.3-2.9l-3.1-2.3l-4.5-1.8l-0.5-1.5l-2.4-2.9l-0.5-1.5l-3.4-4.9l-3.4,0.2l-4.1-3l-1.3-1.3l-0.3-1.8   l0.8-1.9l2.4-1.2l-1.1-1.2l0.1-0.3l-5.8,1l-7,0.8L863.6,458z"/>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet so I'll answer here; you could try in adding a ::after or ::before element, with the content set to the respective states abbreviation, positioned with position:absolute via css relatively to the corresponding state path tag (which in turn have position :relative), then center them with flexbox css or top / bottom values / auto margins. Just an idea, that's how i did it for sth similar and I really liked the idea of doing it all via css only.

**UPDATE**

More Precisely, this solution is for WEBPAGES CONTAINING SVG only: you can simply wrap a given SVG  tag into a wrapper div html tag with id = wrapper-div, and then simply do #wrapper-div::after or even #wrapper-div path::after in your stylesheet, according to your svg's / path tags / preferences; this works without problems. And yeah you can simply import an SVG into a web page by pasting its tags into a php / html page.

**EXAMPLE**

Actually, for your case, given that your labels are static, you might to prefer simple text tags and position them according to your svg with the correct coordinates; probably the solution you'd prefer, so check out my exmaple which does not need any Js AT ALL (I'm not sure if my fiddle works properly, so I copied the code here too:)

HTML:

```
<div id="map-container">
  <svg id="states-map" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <path id="state-A" d="M17.000,52.000 C17.000,52.000 12.172,40.787 18.000,39.000 C23.828,37.213 29.028,10.671 43.000,34.000 C87.872,108.924 8.795,87.742 27.000,72.000 C17.397,80.304 17.000,52.000 17.000,52.000 Z" class="cls-1"/>
  <path id="state-B" d="M36.000,25.000 L42.000,31.000 L45.000,37.000 L48.000,43.000 L51.000,49.000 L54.000,57.000 L56.000,63.000 L57.000,74.000 L53.000,81.000 L50.000,85.000 L73.000,85.000 C73.000,85.000 82.218,100.400 81.000,77.000 C79.782,53.600 97.725,38.708 91.000,33.000 C84.275,27.292 84.421,21.665 72.000,20.000 C59.579,18.335 36.000,25.000 36.000,25.000 Z" class="cls-1"/>
  <text id="label-state-B" x="58" y="51" class="cls-2"><tspan class="cls-3">SB</tspan></text>
  <text id="label-state-A" x="25" y="62" class="cls-2"><tspan class="cls-3">SA</tspan></text>
</svg>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#map-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 250px;
  width: 100%;
}

#states-map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#state-A,
#state-B {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: #000;
  z-index: 90;
}

[id^="label-state-"] {
  display: none;
}

#states-map:hover [id^="label-state-"] {
  display: block;
}

#state-A:hover,
#state-B:hover {
  fill: lightgreen;
  cursor: pointer;
}

tspan {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS";
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

In case you wanna remove the state label animations appearing and disappearing, just remove these lines from your CSS:

```
[id^="label-state-"] {
  display: none;
}

#states-map:hover [id^="label-state-"] {
  display: block;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k1f3h9pg/2/)

Hope you like it! One last note:

- To position your state labels statically, use the "x" and "y" attributes of the respective text tags. Don't worry, they're always positioned in relation to your svg x-y map, so you can resize the svg without changing the relative positioning of your state labels. What I mean is, in my fiddle, feel free to change the height and width values of the #states-map; you'll see that the map gets resized, but the state labels won't lose their centered positioning, which is why I love doing SVG that way.

Comment: it would be awesome to see a fiddle with this

Comment: aight one sec, I'll do sth quickly

Comment: Added above, hope u like it!